# Why IS this code working properly?

Tags: scheme, racket

I thought the following code would not properly remove leading and trailing zeros, but it does:

```
(define f
  (λ (l)
    (let loop ()                             ; 1 (code line no.)
      (when (= 0 (first l))                  ; 2
        (set! l (rest l))                    ; 3
        (loop))                              ; 4
      (set! l (reverse l) )                  ; 5
      (when (= 0 (first l)) (loop)))         ; 6
    (reverse l)))                            ; 7

(f '(0 0 2 5 0 6 8 9 0 0 0))
```

Output:

```
'(2 5 0 6 8 9)
```

I thought that after removing leading zeros, the list will get reversed in line 5; then from line 6 it will recurse to line 1 and remove the trailing zeros (which are now leading in the reversed list). Then this list will get reversed again (second time at line 5) and finally it will get reverse again (third time) at line 7.

Since the list is getting reversed 3 times, a reversed list (without zeros) should be the output, however, non-reversed list is being shown in output. Where is the flaw in the explanation?

Comment: The code you posted is not the one you linked to. This one combines mutation and recursion, which is an unpleasant combination to reason about. The one you linked is purely functional.

Comment: I had changed the code in that link after finding out that it was defective. I have removed the link from my question. Thanks for pointing out the oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that when the loop returns the program continues to execute after the line 4. This happens for each call of the loop. So if there are n leading zeros and m trailing zeros the `reverse` will be called `n + 1 + m + 1 + 1 = n + m + 3` (last `1` is the reverse at the end of program), which in the example case is 8.

However, you are right in that the program doesn't work as running

```
(f '(0 0 2 5 0 6 8 9 0 0))
```

will output

```
'(9 8 6 0 5 2)
```

Comment: Hence, my hunch was correct that this code is not fully correct.